# How to set up an Entity Framework data model to use one entity model for multiple views?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have got multiple views with exactly same records structure but different filtering logic. I'd like to be able to query any of them with Entity Framework and it would seem much more natural if they would be returning values of same type instead of using a different type (with exactly same members) for every view. How to achieve this?

I use visual model designer with database-first approach.

UPDATE:

For example: we can have `Vehicles` table,

```
create view [GreenVehicles] as select * from [Vehicles] where [Color]='Green';
```

and

```
create view [GreenVans] as select * from [GreenVehicles] where [Type]='Van';
```

The task is to make it so that we would be able to query `GreenVans` as a collection of `GreenVehicles`.

Comment: Do you mean using the same set of data? Or just keeping the data model, regardless of data?

Comment: I mean having single record entity class for multiple data sets. Sou that results of querying table/view a and table/view b (which have exactly same fields definitions) would be of the same type.

Comment: If you work code-first you could create multiple context classes that map the type to a different view each. It's the only option I see for you with EF. I must admit I never tried, so I'm not sure if EF has some "surprises" in store if you do this.

Comment: Are you using EF inheritance?

Comment: No, I couldn't figure out how to set it up, @Bob.

Comment: I'd suggest having a view of [Entity Framework Database First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878) and then having a read of [Entity Framework Modeling Table Per Type Inheritance](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance/).

Comment: I am not sure TPT fits well if your example is as described - unless green vehicles or vans seperate classes inherited from vehicle with unique properties for that vehicle type. (i.e. a pickup truck may extend vehicle, and have an additional field for "bed capacity" and therefore be an extension of the original - possibly abstract - vehicle class), but for something as described above I think you are really looking at a simple filter.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE / 3]**

I removed my original example altogether, as it has nothing to do with this on clarification. What you are looking for is to return the IQueryable object and adding filters to it before executing on it. This (in my understanding) will cause all work to still be done serverside and a good discussion of it can be found here:

http://codethinked.com/keep-your-iqueryable-in-check

Corrections are welcome!

Comment: Here you do the filtering at the model code level. But in my case filtering is done at the SQL Server side = there are `GreenVehicles` and `GreenVehicles` views prepared already and I am to read the records from them, not from the `Vehicles` table directly. I need to query `_context.GreenVans` and get `ICollection<GreenVehicles>` as the result (providing that `GreenVehicles` and `GreenVans` have exactly same member fields sets).

Comment: My example is limited by memory here, so yes, using the context and where will provide you with a collection (not what you want) but I am certian I have done this somewhere where I return an IQueryable and then complete further filtering before actually causing the DB call to execute. This seems to be on the same track? http://www.codethinked.com/keep-your-iqueryable-in-check